# Filter to strip unnecessary attributes

Tags: functions, filters

I'm looking for a concise PHP filter to add to my functions.php that will search for and strip the following attributes I don't want in my HTML:

- rel="attachment"
- rel="attachment wp-att-{x}"
- rel="category"
- rel="category tag"
- rel="bookmark"
- rel="author"
- pubdate

I'm happy for all "rel" attributes to be stripped (rather than just what's listed above) if that's easier.

Comment: What is your "theme output"? Are you referring to `the_content`?

Comment: Sorry, question clarified.

Comment: I'm sorry too: I still don't understand what you want/need. The "output" or "HTML" _of which function_ exactly?

Comment: Any. I'd like these attributes removed from my whole theme.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more clear: (From the comments on the question)

> **Q:** The "output" or "HTML" of which function exactly?
>
> **A:** Any. I'd like these attributes removed from my whole theme.

### WP & Functions:

WordPress has around 2.5k functions with the current version 3.4.2. Now imagine, that we would (or even could) check each function *before* it is run and then intercept with a `str_replace`, `preg_replace` or similar: We would probably slow your theme down by a factor of 10-100.

### Alternate approach(es):

**NOTE:** Not that I'd suggest any of that.

- You could use `ob_start()`, etc. and catch the output, parse it and bring it back in.
- Use js to manually remove it after the DOM has loaded

**NOW** this is my suggestion: Simply don't do it. The `rel="whatever"` attributes don't harm anyone or anything. The opposite is the case: Google (and other SEs) have a much easier time finding and indexing your content.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](http://josephleedy.me/blog/make-wordpress-category-list-valid-by-removing-rel-attribute) last year about how to remove `rel="category tag"`. Perhaps you can adapt the code to suit your own needs.

```
// Remove rel attribute from the category list
function wpa_64682_remove_category_list_rel( $output )
{
    $output = str_replace( ' rel="category tag"', '', $output );
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'wpa_64682_remove_category_list_rel' );
add_filter( 'the_category', 'wpa_64682_remove_category_list_rel' );
```